# InvalidStateError when trying to convert CSV File

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, blob

I have the following JS function, running in '*onclick*' of my HTML button:

```js
function exportarDadosRelatorio2() {
    if ($("#Relatorio").val() != "") {
        var listaParametrosTela = construirParametrosTela();

        var busca = $('#formRelatorio').serializeObject();
        busca.ListaParametrosTela = listaParametrosTela;

        var envio = JSON.stringify({ pModel: busca });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Relatorios/ExportarDadosRelatorio2",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: envio,
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (response) {
                //var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/ms-excel' });
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/csv' });
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = "relatorio.csv";
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        mostrarMensagemEmBalao("", "Selecionar um relatório para ser gerado.");
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to read the response and create a new Blob:
*var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/csv' });*
I get an error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 98, column 17 in http://localhost:30680/Scripts/Modulos/Relatorios/Index.js

0x800a139e - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: InvalidStateError
```

I tried to use the following type, but also didn't work:

```
type: 'application/ms-excel'
```

This is the 'response.responseText' content (just the initial lines):

```
EXECUTIVO DE CONTA;RAZÃO SOCIAL;NOME FANTASIA;CNPJ
PAULO FENDLER JUNIOR;ACCOR BRASIL;ACCOR;09967852000127
PAULO FENDLER JUNIOR;AERONAUTICA;;
PAULO FENDLER JUNIOR;AERONAUTICA;;
PAULO FENDLER JUNIOR;AERONAUTICA;;
PAULO FENDLER JUNIOR;AERONÁUTICA;;
PAULO FENDLER JUNIOR;ASSEMBLEIA LEGISLATIVA DO ESTADO DE SAO PAULO;ASSEMBLEIA LEGISLATIVA;59952259000185
```

Please, any sugestions?

This is the imagem error:
[VS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSZ0s.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify how this question relates to C#? This seems to be entirely about Javascript.

Comment: it seems you just posted on internet the full name and sensible information from some government member...

Answer (score 0):

Reason is your not parsing in JSON format. For blob you must first parse data into JSON using below JSON.stringify
Hope it will work let me know

```
var resjson= JSON.stringify(response);
 var blob = new Blob([resjson], { type: 'text/csv' });
```